# jQuery scrolltop not moving to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am using scrolltop to move to the bottom of the scroll:

```
 // Auto-scroll to the bottom
 $("#test_div").scrollTop($("#test_div")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Here is the div element:

```
<div class="dialog">
    <div id="test_div" class="conversation">
    </div>​
</div>
```

For some reasons, the scroller is not moving to the bottom of the list. I am not sure whether anything is wrong here.

Comment: hello, it seems to work good :) http://jsfiddle.net/pjSmp/

Comment: @Stano's implementation works for me too (in Chrome and Firefox). Perhaps it's a browser issue or there's something else wrong with your code.  Perhaps you can provide your own jsfiddle or some more details about what's going wrong (debug error messages, perhaps)?

Comment: @Stano thanks for the feedback. I got multiple tabs in my page. #test_div doesn't appear on page load until user clicks the tab. But the contents of test_div are populated on the page load itself. This may be because the div is not on focus? I verified this by directly loading the tab and scrolltop works fine. Any suggestions?